# Can I actually interact with trade ships in space?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I was flying around the starting system in frame shift mode and saw a point of interest that said "seeking luxuries". I flew there to check it out and ran into three trade ships. I couldn't seem to interact with them (other than attacking them, I suppose).

Is there any reason to visit these points of interest? Is there some way to interact with them or sell luxuries to them?

Comment: Good question, seen this too NPC ships asking for several types of goods through com.

Comment: I never have what they're looking for, but if you do, you could try dropping a container of that trade good and see what happens...

Answer (score 8):

Whilst I have not done this myself, I have read several times on the official forums that other players have.  If you have the items the ships are seeking, they are magically taken from you and you are automatically paid for them.

I can only assume that you get paid a considerable amount more than you would get selling them at any station or you could end up quite upset if you lost out on potential profit.

This wouldn't stop situations where you had bought the cargo for a "Please bring me X tons of Y" type mission from a bulletin board and the cargo was taken from you.

Edit: Confirmation of the "fly close" mechanic.
https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=96996&p=1507483&viewfull=1#post1507483
This thread also clarifies what is a "luxury item", in this case players are trading Progenitor Cells with these mobile markets.

Comment: They just get directly taken from you, without it asking for your approval? That sounds like terrible game design.

Comment: I also read that if you scan their cargo they tell you what they are looking for.

Comment: @Sterno - Only terrible if you really needed the cargo for a mission, or if the price they give you is terrible.To be honest, it isn't a great mechanism though.  I suspect it is a feature that was quite cheap to add in terms of development, but really needs some attention to make more user friendly when they get the time.

Comment: I've done the "luxuries", and here are some additional information: a) the traders will pay the black-market value for the given goods (most of the time they are seeking performance enhancers, albeit supposedly there are other goods they want), b) you can use a cargo scanner on the traders to see the type of good they are looking for c) money made this way is, strangely, counted to the "smuggling" statistic - this means you might have trouble increasing in trading rank if you do this

Answer (score 5):

I just sold 212 cargo of battle weapons to the Seeking Weapons dealers. They paid 1,599,000 for all of them. I paid about 6400 each for them, and their deal comes out to 7500 or so. Made over 300K profit on one quick run. The bonus is that you dont have to sneak into a station and possibly get fined. You fly close to them 1.5km or so and they auto take it out of your hold. Instant payment in the info window.

Edit, personal weapons dont count. I tried 10 units of this and nothing. Wasted my time on it. Dumped those and bought the above Battle Weapons and made bank.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it.  I had 16T of Rutile and went into a USS and let a Type 9 called The Mineral Magpie.  I flew close and it took all 16 tons and gave 7936 credits.  Much more than I would of got at the starport

Answer (score 0):

these profit margins are comparable to what i can find on the minimum trade market i dont go to stations that scan my cargo and i dont have a problem jumping back and forth once i apply my trade route it gets pretty quick. Interesting though nonetheless but i dont think these ships warrant enough payout for the value(especially if it goes into the smugglers catagory and not trade where you can pick up higher rank leading to better paid missions and reputation rank)